# ImportCSV from GoogleDrive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hello and HAPPY father's day to all.

Trying to currently IMPORT a CSV file from a designated folder and specific file name based on Cell value A2 and B2 into a target SHEET(lets say INPUT), which I have not coded yet because I'm troubleshooting the first step of importing the CSV.

Do I have the right function? Or am I totally off.  Any help or point in the right direction is appreciated.

```
function importCSV() {

  // get current spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // get folder
   var id = ss.getSheetByName("Dashboard").getRange("B1").getValue();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(id); // <--- your folder ID goes here 
  
  // get file name from the cell 
  var name = ss.getSheetByName("Dashboard").getRange("A2").getValue();
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(name).next();

  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
```

Comment: You need to include the extension in the file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function importCSV() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const id = ss.getSheetByName("Dashboard").getRange("B1").getValue();
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(id);
  const name = ss.getSheetByName("Dashboard").getRange("A2").getValue();
  const file = folder.getFilesByName(name).next();
  const csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
}
```

I just tested it and the filename includes the extension.  If you include the extension it works.  Without the extension you get the error.

Comment: Was hoping your solution was it.  But seem to get a VERY similar error to what I have a above. 

"Exception: Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end.
importCSV"

Comment: Evidently no files with that name in that folder

Comment: Ahhh yes you nailed it on the head.  Apparently I must add the file type for whatever reason.  Many THANKS!!!!

Comment: In Google Drive the extension is not necessarily the file type.  It's just part of the name.